# Driving parallel channels with 1 PWM signal

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, led-driver

I am currently developing a protoboard for an LED driver having PWM control for dimming using a microcontroller. I plan to drive a number of parallel channels of LEDs ('n' number of RGB channels) and have it opto-isolated as well.

My question is, is it okay to drive these parallel strings using 'n' numbers of PWM channels to lessen the number of GPIOs needed for generating the PWM signals? My plan was to independently dim the three color channels using only three PWM outputs providing the PWM signals only dimming by color (say 3 RGB channels, 1 PWM signal for the three channels of red... and so on). What other factors must I consider such as how it may affect the duty cycles and other dimming/control variables if I plan to do such setup?

Comment: Some information missing, not clear...  Do you wnat to drive with one only PWM signal , many Red LEDs in series, in parallel, in series//parallel gangs ?  Please show us some kind of diagram.

Comment: Yes, the idea is correct. One signal for let's say three parallel strings of red, and another signal for blue, so I won't need to generate a signal for each parallel channel since I only need to dim per color and not per channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, if I boil down the question, it will be "can I route one PWM signal to multiple components/devices"? If so, the answer is yes, you can.

There are minor caveats that limit your peak frequency, because the trace itself has non-zero capacitance, but if your PWM is in lower MHz - Arduino level frequencies, you don't have anything at all to worry about.

It would be a good idea to have a resistor on the PWM output, because the capacitance of the trace means you will be charging/discharging that trace like a tiny cap, and there will be high instantaneous currents. You don't want that (same thing as driving individual MOSFET gate with Arduino). It will probably work, but better put some 120 - 330 Ohm between PWM driver and everything else it connects to. For peace of mind.

Like here (random picture, just an illustration of a resistor on PWM output, [picture source](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/which-mosfet-as-switch-for-arduino-mini-pro-3-3v/574273)):
[image]

Also, you don't want to run multiple different PWM signals too close together in parallel, have a little distance between them so that they don't couple together. By "too close" I mean a few mm should already be enough. Obviously, without specifics regarding frequency (and PWM rise/fall time) I can't provide and specifics in this regard too, but all in all for a basic project it's probably not something you should worry about too much, just be aware that such thing exists, maybe do basic research on how switching noise is induced (rise time, fall time, etc.).

Comment: Yes, this is the idea. Thank you for the answer.